# No image in Preview RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am on RStudio and trying to display the output of a Noteboook in Preview, but actually the output that I am getting is:

[image]

I set "Chunck Output in Console" option but the output is the above.
The Notebook starts with:

```
---
title: "Tutorial Generalized Random Forest"
output: html_notebook
runtime: shiny_prerendered
description: "Generalized Random Forest"
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---
```

Can someone figure out this? Maybe some package not updated?

Thank you,

Federico

Comment: Is there a reason for `runtime: shiny_prerendered`? I'm thinking that's the culprit.

Comment: I have some interactive scripts that require it. Maybe I try to arrange them in another way so that to avoid shiny_prerendered

Comment: @Phil Actually this line ```{r cf, exercise=TRUE, exercise.eval=FALSE } requires it. Moreover the plots appear in the plots window but not in Preview